# Simple Code throws expected ; error

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have created a simple Code using if else clause,it throws error like expected ";". But when I check the code everything seems correct. I am new to C# coding.

```
public string empstatus(string trmdate, string status)
 { 
   if( trmdate!= NULL)
     { 
       if(status = "RETIREE") 
         { 
           return "RT"; 
         } 
       else retun "FT"; 
     } 
   else return "TF";
 }
```

Comment: `NULL` isn't a null literal in c#. It should be `null`

Comment: Also, in any version of visual studio, double click on the compiler error will lead you to the code line that generated the error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am using C# in BizTalk application. Its not showing the line which has error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about c# operators - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

You should compare 2 objects by using '==' operator.

```
if (status == "RETIREE")
```

Answer (score 9):

This compiles:

```
public string empstatus(string trmdate, string status)
{ 
   if( trmdate!= null)
   { 
       if(status == "RETIREE") 
       { 
          return "RT"; 
       } 
       else return "FT"; 
   } 
   else 
       return "TF";
}
```

Mistakes:

1. `retun` instead of `return`
2. `if(status = "RETIREE")` instead of `if(status == "RETIREE")`
3. NULL instead of null

Comment: The only answer that fixes all 3 issues.  But you should mention what they were.

Comment: Actually, the entire function can be a one liner: `return (trmdate!= null) ? (status == "RETIREE") ? "RT" : "FT" : "TF" ;`

Comment: @ZoharPeled On readability, I prefer the multi-liner. For the compiler, those are the same anyway, so I'd go with the multi-liner.

Comment: @11684 Actually, they are both more or less on the same readability in my eyes. Anyway it's just a suggestion...

Answer (score 7):

`if(status = "RETIREE")` should be `if(status == "RETIREE")`

Also consider checking status for Null.

Comment: If he uses `==` operator, no need to check for null.

Comment: I tried this but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: see my answer, it compiles

Comment: You also miss-spelt return on the 4th last line.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I should be keen in observing my mistakes

Comment: Maybe you should approve the answer that fixes all mistakes too :-)

Comment: @PaoloCosta I also think your answer was the best in this page.

Comment: It was more a speed race than a question :-)

Answer (score 1):

explicit equasion == in c# is used to test the value of variable, while equasion = is used for value assignment